# Add -100px to jquery (body).height();

Tags: jquery

If I use `(body).height();` to calculate a windows height, is there a way to calculate the height -100px.

Is there a way to do this as part of the `(body).height();` query rather than calculating it later on ?

Comment: Am I missing where this isn't just arithmetic?

Comment: Are you asking for `$('body').height()-100`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
($(body).height() - 100)
```

Just... subtract?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to calculate it each time and deducting 100, you can define a custom function that will do it for you:

```
function bodyHeight() {
    return $("body").height()-100;
}
```

And then just call `bodyHeight()` instead of `$("body").height()`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be :

```
var H = $(body).height() - 100 + 'px';
console.log(H);
```